# What I code in the Design Editor isn't what I get on output

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a program in Visual Studio using WPF and I've stumbled upon a problem

[image]

This is what it looks like when I'm creating it

[image]

But when I run the program, the border goes offscreen, some text and other elements get repositioned or just outright disappear.
Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

So far I've been looking at a few other stack qna's and some say stuff about margins and alignment, others about row definitions and stuff. I've tried all of them and its pretty confusing tbh.

I dont know if I could've been more concise with this (seems kinda overwhelming) but heres the full XAML code for the page in question, hopefully, it helps.

```
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:New_EZexeat"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="560" d:DesignWidth="960"
      Title="Page2">

    <Grid Background="#FF8F8FF9">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="249*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="311*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="signupBorder" 
                Background="#f2f2f2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Height="498" 
                Width="504"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                CornerRadius="5" Margin="228,31" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFA2A2A2" Opacity="0.61" BlurRadius="30" Direction="-27" ShadowDepth="16"/>
            </Border.Effect>

            <!-- Create Account Header -->
            <Border Background="LightCoral"
                    Margin="0,0,0,469"
                    Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle1}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="textinborder" 
                           Text="Create a new account"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           Foreground="#f2f2f2"
                           FontSize="17"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>

        <!-- Students Name -->
        <TextBlock Text="Students Name" 
                   Margin="254,73,582,0" 
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" 
                   TextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="15" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Foreground="Gray"/>
        <TextBox Width="320"
                 Height="30"
                 Margin="-77,-105,0,0"
                 TextAlignment="Left"
                 FontSize="17"
                 Padding="0 0 0 0"
                 BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="324" Y="203"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>

        <!-- School Name -->
        <TextBlock Text="Name of School" 
            Margin="254,152,582,0" 
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" 
            TextAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="15" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Foreground="Gray"/>
        <TextBox Width="320"
            Height="30"
            Margin="-77,-26,0,0"
            TextAlignment="Left"
            FontSize="17"
            Padding="0 0 0 0"
            BorderBrush="Transparent" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="324" Y="203"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>

        <!-- House Name -->
        <TextBlock Text="Name of House" 
            Margin="254,230,582,0" 
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" 
            TextAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="15" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Foreground="Gray" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox Width="320"
            Height="30"
            Margin="-77,52,0,0"
            TextAlignment="Left"
            FontSize="17"
            Padding="0 0 0 0"
            BorderBrush="Transparent" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="324" Y="203"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>

        <!-- Home Address -->
        <TextBlock Text="Home Address" 
            Margin="254,60,582,0" 
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" 
            TextAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="15" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Foreground="Gray" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Width="320"
            Height="30"
            Margin="-77,131,0,0"
            TextAlignment="Left"
            FontSize="17"
            Padding="0 0 0 0"
            BorderBrush="Transparent" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="324" Y="203"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>

        <!-- Parents Numbers -->
        <TextBlock Text="Parents Numbers" 
            Margin="254,133,582,0" 
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" 
            TextAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="15" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Foreground="Gray" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Width="320"
            Height="30"
            Margin="-77,204,0,0"
            TextAlignment="Left"
            FontSize="17"
            Padding="0 0 0 0"
            BorderBrush="Transparent" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="324" Y="203"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Width="320"
            Height="30"
            Margin="-77,2,0,0"
            TextAlignment="Left"
            FontSize="17"
            Padding="0 0 0 0"
            BorderBrush="Transparent" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="324" Y="203"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>

        <!-- Next Button -->
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="693,193,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                FontSize="50"
                FontWeight="Black"
                Width="76"
                Style="{StaticResource CircleButton}" 
                Height="74" 
                Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Button.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="24" Color="#FF6E6E6E" Opacity="0.5" Direction="553"/>
            </Button.Effect>
        </Button>

        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" 
                   Text="&#8594;"
                   FontSize="40"
                   FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                   Foreground="#F2F2F2" 
                   Margin="712,203,0,0" 
                   Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: When using XAML make sure never to use the Designer with the mouse you need to write the XAML yourself similar to HTML
if you want more help we need your XAML-code

Comment: There's a design height and width as well as height and width for a window. The former apply only in designer. Oh. And it is indeed usual to type xaml and use the designer as an indication of what you will get. You might like https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32610.wpf-layout-lab.aspx

Comment: Ok, I've added the XAML code as requested

Comment: Been here for sometime, any answers?

Comment: from the screenshots what I understood is that , the parent window of your Page2 lacks sufficient height and width try setting this to `Width="960" Height="590"` your `Easy Exeat` wpf window. try that